Crear expresion regular en java corchetes
Quiero crear una expresión regular la cual coincida con números o letras además de .,_- y espacios, pero que este entre dos corchetes algo así
[7/4, 8:26 a. m.]

Intentos
cree esta expresión mas sin embargo no coincide lo que busco String patron="\\[[a-zA-Z0-9\\-_,.:/ ]\\]";

No coincide porque olvidaste agregar un + después del rango \\[[a-zA-Z0-9\\-_,.:/ ]+\\]. Te recomiendo probar las expresiones en https://regex101.com/ y una vez que están listas, las copias y escapas los caracteres que sean necesarios.

Despues de investigar y probar encontre la solucion \[(.*?)\]
